# Need a simple circuit to drive 12 volt LED from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I need a MOSFET based circuit to switch on and off a 12 volt LED from a Raspberry Pi. The MOSFET should drive from 3.3V.

Comment: Do you know what should be the current consumption of the LED(s) ? It will help to find an appropriate transistor.

Comment: less than 500ma